# How to access windowStartTime?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to use the windowStartTime parameter to access files that use a date based folder structure.

I have the below trigger:

```
{
    "name": "trigger1",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipeline": {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "Neil_Test",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "Window1": {
                "type": "Expression",
                "value": "@{trigger().outputs.windowStartTime}"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "frequency": "Hour",
            "interval": 24,
            "startTime": "2019-08-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            "delay": "00:00:00",
            "maxConcurrency": 1,
            "retryPolicy": {
                "intervalInSeconds": 30
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    }
}
```

This sets the `Window1` parameter on the pipeline object to `NULL`.
How do I get actual the value of the windowStartTime parameter into my pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue here are the {}. This one is working fine for me:

```
{
"name": "triggerwin",
"properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "runtimeState": "Started",
    "pipeline": {
        "pipelineReference": {
            "referenceName": "setVar",
            "type": "PipelineReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "FileName": "@trigger().outputs.windowStartTime"
        }
    },
    "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15,
        "startTime": "2019-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "delay": "00:00:00",
        "maxConcurrency": 50,
        "retryPolicy": {
            "intervalInSeconds": 30
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
}
}
```

[image: Parameter shown]

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Amazed that the braces don't just compile out, but that seems to be the cause of the issue.